# When designing an experiment, when is it worth duplicating runs to improve error estimates?

Tags: experiment-design, statistical-power, error

In reading about response surface modeling, I learned about the [central composite design](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pri/section3/pri3361.htm), and how repeated center points have the following three results:

1. able to fit/model quadratic factor combinations
2. decrease the response variance
3. improve the estimate of measurement error

Specifically looking at 3, when would it be worthwhile to invest additional measurements to duplicate runs at non-center points?  It seems duplicate points at additional combinations would provide a more complete estimate of the error over the measurement region, i.e., perhaps the measurement error varies as a function of the parameters or the response level.  Is this common practice, and if so, in what situations?